# Problems linking debug setting DLL to project

Tags: c++, linker

I have a project in which I put all my code which references "bad" third party libraries. I have 2 hardware components which won't run properly with Release Mode settings.

The suggestion here was "Compile the third-party library in a separate module, in debug mode. Compile the rest of the application in release mode."

When I put them in their own module, when trying to link to it, I get tons of

```
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0'
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease'
```

I've tried compiling as DLL, but then the linker from the application itself has unresolved symbols, and when linking to the .lib it gives the above errors.

What do I need to do here?

Comment: ***What do I need to do here?*** Compile everything in Release. It's not safe to mix Release and Debug in the same application unless the dll isolates memory allocations and do not pass any stl between the two. The reason is you will have more than 1 independent heap which you can not safely allocate memory in 1 heap and free it in the other.

Comment: But I have a third party library which only returns valid results in debug mode. Am I just screwed here and need to run everything in debug?

Comment: I would contact the vendor of the third party library. Also if this is a product you can not release debug dlls as part of your product since debug dlls can only run on computers with Visual Studio installed. It is against the Visual Studio licence to ship MS debug runtimes so this would force your customers to have to purchase Visual Studio to run your application.